# IIS ApplicationPool fails to start properly without error

Tags: iis, iis-10, application-pool

We are facing a strange issue with our IIS Deployments.

ApplicationPools sometimes fail to start properly but do not throw errors when doing so.
The only containing site within the Application Pool is not responsive (not even returning 500 or the like, just times out after some time).

The ApplicationPool and Sites are up and running (not stopped) as far as IIS is concerned.

Restarting the Site or the ApplicationPool does not fix the issue.

However, removing the site and ApplicationPool and recreating it with identical Properties does fix it.

Once any ApplicationPool has reached this state, the only way to solve this (as far as we know) is recreating the entire ApplicationPool.

We would gladly do so in an automated way, but there is no error to catch and handle respectively.

Some background data:

- We are using IIS Version 10
- The ApplicationPool appears to start correctly. EventLog states that `Application '<OUR_APP>' started successfully.`

We suspect that the problem might be multiple ApplicationPool-starts happening simultaniously (as they are automatically triggered by our CI/CD Pipeline).

Now, I am by no means an IIS Expert, so my questions are:

- **Would it be possible, that many app pool starts (circa 20-60) happening at roughly the same time cause such behaviour?**
- **What could I do to investigate this further?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be caused by our Deployment Scripts not waiting for Application-Pools to actually be in `Stopped` state, before continuing to remove old application files and replacing them with the new ones and immediately Starting the ApplicationPools again.

We noticed issues related to this earlier this year when files could not be deleted because the were still being used, even after stopping the ApplicationPool (which we "solved" by implementing a retry mechanism)...

### Solution

Calling the following code after stopping the ApplicatonPool seems to solve the issue....

```
$stopWaitCount = 0;
while ((Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $appPool).Value -ne "Stopped" -and $stopWaitCount -lt 12)
{
    $stopWaitCount++
    Write-Log "Waiting for Application-Pool '$appPool' to stop..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $stopWaitCount
}
```

We implemented this 2 days ago and the problem didn't occur in 100+ deployments since.

Answer (score 3):

> Would it be possible, that many app pool starts (circa 20-60)
> happening at roughly the same time cause such behaviour?

Difficult to say. An app pool is just an empty container, mostly what takes the time and places limits on this number is what your application code and dependencies are doing at startup and runtime with a little dotnet precompilation overhead.

> What could I do to investigate this further?

1. Check the HTTPERR logs in the Windows folder - might provide a clue if your not seeing the request logged elsewhere.
2. monitor the w3wp.exe processes themselves - those are your apppools(AKA "app domains"). Its possible for them to get stuck and not "properly" crash which sounds like your case.

Assuming all your apps normally work and you just want a way to recover random failures, try this...

When you have a broken app pool, run the following on your server from PowerShell or ISE (as an Administrator) to view the running IIS worker processes:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'w3wp.exe'" | Select-Object ProcessId,CommandLine
```

Above outputs the worker processes ID's, and the arguments used to start them. Among the arguments you can see the sites name - use the correct ProcessId with the command `Stop-Process -Force -Id X` (replacing `X` with the ProcessId number) to forcibly kill the process. Does the app successfully start once you try and access it after killing the process?

If you know the name of the app pool to kill you can use this code to terminate the process:

```
$AppPoolName = 'NAMEOFMYAPPPOOL';
Stop-Process -Force -id (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'w3wp.exe' AND CommandLine like '%-in%$($AppPoolName)%'").ProcessId
```

(substitute `NAMEOFMYAPPPOOL` for the name of the app pool, and run as Administrator)

If killing the stalled process is sufficient to let it restart successfully it would be fairly easy to script a simple health check. I would read the bindings of each site, make an HTTP request to each binding and confirm the app pool really is running/responsive and returns a 200 OK response. If the request fails after some reasonable timeout, try terminating the process and re-requesting the HTTP request to restart the app pool. Add some retry logic and maybe add a delay between attempts so it doesnt get stuck in a loop.

Just a thought - try giving each app pool its own temp folder - configured in web.config per site:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation tempDirectory="D:\tempfiles\apppoolname" />
```

Cross talk in here during startup is a possible source of weirdness.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this once the problem arises again!